# unable to downgrade heroku version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to use ruby 1.9.3 on my heroku app and following this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

I set `ruby '1.9.3'` in my gemfile as instructed

when deploying my app, the log tells me

```
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
```

...

```
-----> WARNINGS:
       you have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:"
       ruby '2.0.0'"
```

I also followed the Troubleshooting instructions on the page and changed the path to ATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin accordingly
Then

`heroku run ruby -v` tells me

```
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]
```

Quite clueless now what else to do.

Thanks for any help.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: I think I'll have to ask to see at least the relevant parts of your gemfile :)

Comment: bundle install, add, commit, push?

Comment: all done probably 1 million times

Comment: btw if I make minor changes to the gemfile, commit and push, heroku sometimes tells me that everything is up to date although that is not the case - maybe this "issue" is related